# Livewire 3 queries old values on view update

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have an application that populates a table depending on the value selected in select box (dropdown).  I have simplified the scenario so I can provide simple code example and explain what my question is.

Livewire Class - Selector.php

```
    class Selector extends Component
{
    public ?Collection $teams = null;
    public ?int $selectedCourt = 1;

    public function mount(): void
    {
        $this->selectedCourt = 1;
        $this->updatedSelectedCourt();
    }

    public function updatedSelectedCourt(): void
    {
        $this->teams = null;
        $this->teams = Team::query()->where('court_id', $this->selectedCourt)->get();
    }
    public function render(): \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
    {
        $courts = Court::query()->orderBy('name')->get();
        return view('livewire.selector', [
            'courts' => $courts
        ]);
    }
}
```

Livewire View - selector.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class="max-w-3xl mx-auto">
        <select wire:model="selectedCourt" name="selectedCourt" id="selectedCourt">
            @foreach($courts as $court)
                <option value="{{$court->id}}">{{$court->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-16">

        <div>Team</div>
        <div>
            @foreach($teams as $team)
                <div>{{$team->name}}</div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Initial load]

On the initial page load the debugbar shows 3 queries.
[image: Debugbar]

On any subsequent update the debubar shows queries for the previous teams plus the 3 queries to generate the new table content.

[image: Second load]
[image]

The queries for the old table content originate from
/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportModels/ModelSynth.php

Are these necessary and if they aren't how do I stop them?

Comment: So first things first .. the use of `query()` is obsolete. Second, why aren't you using the relationship between `Court` and `Team`, something like `Court::get($this->selectedCourt)->teams`? Are you sure these queries are executed (e.g. using telescope or a db dump). It could be showing a pre-run. The *debugbar* isn't always playing nice and can show false results, I have had too many of those and it's absolute; not worth the time to investigate why, just dump it.

Comment: I am not sure why it's doing it one by one, but it's very likely to be the rehydration of your component, since `$teams` is a public property. Each request it will re-fetch them from the database. Also, I would suggest using `wire:key` in loops, it will prevent weird HTML errors.

Comment: PHPStorm code completion works better when I use query.